# Mongoose update with limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I am looking to update `X documents` all at once.  The short is I basically need to randomly select `N documents` and then update them as `"selected"`.  I'm trying to design an API that needs to randomly distribute questions.  I can not find a way to do this in mongoose I have tried:

`update` ends up selecting everything

```
Question
  .update({}, {
    $inc: {
      answerCount: 1,
      lockedCount: 1
    },
    $push:{
      devices: deviceID
    }
}, {multi:true})
 .limit(4)
```

--- I also tried

```
Question
.find()
.sort({
   answerCount: 1,
   lockedCount: 1
})
.limit(req.query.limit || 4)
.update({}, {
    $inc: {
      answerCount: 1,
      lockedCount: 1
    },
    $push:{
      devices: deviceID
    }
}, { multi: true },  callback);
```

Both resulted in updating all docs.  Is there a way to push this down to mongoose without having to use `map` ?  The other thing I did not mention is `.update()` without multi resulted in 1 document being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did an simple `map` implementation and will use it unless someone can find a more efficient way to do it.

```
Question
  .find({
     devices: { $ne: deviceID}
    }, 
    { name: true, _id: true})
  .sort({
    answerCount: 1,
    lockedCount: 1
   })
  .limit(req.query.limit || 4)
  .exec(updateAllFound );

function updateAllFound(err, questions) {
  if (err) {
    return handleError(res, err);
  }
  var ids = questions.map(function(item){
    return item._id;
  });

  return Question.update({  _id: { $in: ids}   } ,
      {
      $inc: {
        answerCount: 1,
        lockedCount: 1
      },
      $push:{
        devices: deviceID
      }
  }, { multi: true }, getByDeviceID);

  function getByDeviceID(){
    return res.json(200, questions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also pull an array of `_id`s that you'd like to update then run the update query using `$in`. This will require two calls to the mongo however the updates will still be atomic:

```
Question.find().select("_id").limit(4).exec(function(err, questions) {

    var q = Question.update({_id: {$in: questions}}, {
        $inc: {answerCount: 1, lockedCount:1},
        $push: {devices: deviceid}
    }, {multi:true});

    q.exec(function(err) {
        console.log("Done");
    });
});
```